# Is there a correct graph which describes various drinks

Tags: health, alcohol-level

I was going through list of drinks [Alcholic] . Was thinking is there any graph which subtly defines to which category of drinks they belong to . A more generic to top down approach of specific type . 
[WIKI LINK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_alcoholic_drinks#Drinks_by_raw_material)

Comment: I believe it would be too difficult to produce a graph for this without it being interactive ie: click here, click there to see other parts of the graph, you certainly couldn't make a printable graph as there are too many variants within the information you are trying to condense.

Comment: You may find some good info in mixology training materials...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't going to be (or rather it wouldn't be visually appealing enough) a source for what you want. Your best bet is to search "::insert alcoholic family you wish here:: Infographics." When you do you will find that some people have made things like this from PopChartLabs! They have two great ones for Whiskey and Scotch too. [image: BeerFam]

Comment: What an interesting chart.